# Unable to import hibernate configuration file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I've used Eclipse Helios with Hibernate Tools installed. Everything worked fine. Now I've changed to Eclipse Kepler. Looks like it has the Hibernate Tools also installed as I'm able to change to Hibernate perspective. When I'm trying to import my old project Hibernate Configurations([as shown here](http://www.soyatec.com/edatabase/com.soyatec.database.doc/database/code/hibernate/import-config/index.html)). The option to import Hibernate Configuration file does not appear. Here is the image of how my import dialog looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you need in this way too:

1. Click on the *+* icon you see highlighted in the top-left corner in the pic
2. Setup all the information for your specific case
3. Click on *Setup ...*
4. Click on *Use existing ...*

[image: Import Existing Hibernate Configuration file]

Hope this will be useful!

Comment: On the dialog, as on your screenshot, has appeared this error `[Classpath]: Problems while loading database driverclass (org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)` but I've solved it by adding jdbc jar file in to Classpath. And it solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed `<type>pom<type>` from the hibernate jar and it worked. Also, please save and update the project.
Which was like this when I copied from Maven repo.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```